# maximum size of entries in memcached

Tags: java, memcached

I am trying to insert around 800k of key-value into memcached, the key is a string of length less than 20 characters and the value is just a float. However after inserting 800k entries, some of the values are 0, while it's not supposed to be 0.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it breaks down"? What happens? According to the [memcached FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ) the [maximum size of a value associated with a key is one megabyte](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_data_size_you_can_store?_%281_megabyte%29), so if you are only storing a float, that should not be, as you stated in the question, the problem.

Comment: let me clarify the question again.. it can finish entering all the 500k entries but after that some values are 0, while it's not supposed to be 0

Answer (score 0):

How do you start memcached? What is the value of *-m* command line argument? This argument means how much ram memcached can use for item storage (MB). In your case the default value may be not enough to store 800k entries and some entries are evicted to make space for new ones.

Try to run memcached with bigger item storage: `memcached -m 512`.

In you tests you may also try `-M` which returns an error on memory exhausted.